# Zend Framework validation: set element value to empty string when there is no data in POST

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, element

I'm sorry if my question is a bit dumb, but I have looked at other questions/Googled this and still didn't get it.

I have a form with default and custom elements:

```
class Form_Client extends Planner_Form {

public function init() {
    $this->addPrefixPath('Planner_Form_Element', 'Planner/Form/Element', 'element');
    $this->setAttrib('name', 'clientForm');

    $this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
        'label'    =>  'Телефон',
        'required' =>  true,
        'filters' => array('Digits'),
        'ng-model' => 'clientForm.phone',
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', 'extra_phone_1', array(
        'label'    => 'Дополнительный телефон',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array(
            array('Digits'),
        ),
        'ng-model' => 'clientForm.extra_phone_1',
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
        'label'    => 'Имя',
        'required' => false,
        'ng-model' => 'clientForm.name',
    ));

    $this->addElement('datetime', 'birthday', array(
        'label'    => 'Дата рождения',
        'required' => false,
        'ng-model' => 'clientForm.birthday',
    ));
```

I send form via AngularJs, and when I check it

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
  $body = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
  $data = Zend_Json::decode($body);
  Zend_Debug::dump($data);

  $form = new Form_Client();
  if ($form->isValid($data)) {
     $values = $form->getValues();
     Zend_Debug::dump($values);
  }
```

I get the following:

```
array(1) {  
  ["phone"] => string(10) "9138521376"
}

array(4) {
  ["phone"] => string(10) "9138521376"
  ["extra_phone_1"] => string(0) ""
  ["name"] => NULL
  ["birthday"] => NULL
}
```

So my question is: why `extra_phone_1` field gets empty string, and `name` gets NULL? Is it because of filter on `extra_phone_1` field? If so, how can I set field value to empty string, when there is no data in POST for this field?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the value is'' due `Digits` filter and null without this filter.
To have a non-null value in the `name` field, for example, you can use the same technique and try to put the filter `'StringTrim'`

Comment: Are you satisfied with this answer?